# Angular2: how to get data attr of select option

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

```
<select id="nameList">
  <option data-age="18" value="Jack">Jack</option>
  <option data-age="28" value="John">John</option>
  <option data-age="18" value="Robbin">Robbin</option>
  <option data-age="38" value="Johnson">Johnson</option>
</select>
<div id="output"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change',"#nameList",function(){
        var age = $("option:selected",this).attr('data-age');
        $("#output").html(age);
    });
});
```

How to implement this one in Angular2 ?
refer this link: https://jsfiddle.net/vqmnLk5u/

Comment: What's your issue ? Can you add some more details on what you've tried and what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Actually I want to add a custom attribute to the options and on change of modal I want to access that custom attribute value in my component. I have an array of objects on which I am ittrating to get the options. And I can't provide my full object to [ngValue] because of some security reasons. So how can I add a custom attr and access that in my component ?